# Fluent NHibernate Mapping with foreign key relationship

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Here is my fluent map for Drops Table

```
this.Table("Drops");
this.LazyLoad();
this.Id(x => x.Guid).GeneratedBy.Guid().Column("Guid");
this.References(x => x.User).column("UserGuid");
this.Map(x => x.FromLocation).Column("FromLocation").Not.Nullable().Length(50);
this.Map(x => x.ToLocation).Column("ToLocation").Not.Nullable().Length(50);
this.Map(x => x.Time).Column("Time").Not.Nullable();
```

Here is my user Table

```
this.Table("Users");
this.LazyLoad();
this.Id(x => x.Guid).GeneratedBy.Guid();
this.Map(x => x.SessionId).Unique().Column("SessionId");
this.Map(x => x.UserName).Unique().Column("UserName");
this.Map(x => x.Password).Column("Password");
this.Map(x => x.NickName).Column("NickName");
this.Map(x => x.FirstName).Column("FirstName");
this.Map(x => x.LastName).Column("LastName");
this.Map(x => x.Gender).Column("Gender");
```

So, Drops included User table,

When I add the drop table, It will added correctly.

What I need is, I need to get the list of drop objects using user SessionId.

I am using below code to get drop collection,

```
session.QueryOver<Drop>().Where(d => d.UserGuid != user.Guid).List();
```

but I am getting below error,

> could not resolve property: UserGuid of:
>   *********.**********.BusinessObjects.Drop

I checked the drop table, UserGuid Column is added

[image]

How to get the drop list or whats the problem there?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
session.QueryOver<Drop>().Where(d => d.User.SessionId != user.SessionId).List();
```

if you are looking up by user session id (or excluding them in your case).

**EDIT**

Sorry, I got so hung up on the initial point that I missed the fact that you need to define an alias for the user object. Try:

```
User alias = null;
session.QueryOver<Drop>().JoinAlias(d=>d.User,()=>alias).Where(d => alias.SessionId != user.SessionId).List();
```

Comment: I got this exception when I am using this "could not resolve property: User.SessionId of: DeposeMoi.DataAccess.BusinessObjects.Drop"

Comment: JTMon : I need to get Collection of drops using users session and also check the My mappings are correct, Thanks.

Comment: In the code included in your original post you had Where(d => d.User.SessionId != user.SessionId) should it be Where(d => d.User.SessionId == user.SessionId)?